# Which CiviCase? Compucore or V5?

Tags: civicase

I am trying to understand which is the 'latest' version of CiviCase to upgrade to, is it:

https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicase

or

https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.civicase

Can anyone advise?!

Comment: you may want to figure out what additional features you require for civicase - we have a lot of sites using the civicase that comes with core and have not used either of the above

Comment: It was less additonal features and more exploring how others had pehaps improved on what we have. For us, CiviCase is used alot and I was aware that there were newer versions that might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer is probably 'both'.  The first one you mention from Compucorp is an enhanced version of the case management in CiviCRM, driven by an extension and a different theme.  The second is the latest version released by the CiviCRM team.  But be aware that the Compucorp version is possibly/probably based on a slightly older version of the CiviCRM case system and so might not work with the latest Civi release.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "better downloaded as part of the release". The org.civicrm.civicase extension is not the same as the core CiviCase included in the core download, it's an extension that is closer to the Compucorp one (the Compucorp one started as a fork of it).

Comment: So my answer is just plain wrong? Perhaps I should delete it?

Comment: Just the middle sentence I don't think is right. The first two are good. The last is correct in the sense that ALL extensions lag behind core somewhat.

Comment: Edited, thanks for the correction

Comment: Thanks guys, all comments much appreciated.  I'll create local dev environments and see what both do.  Seem a little odd to have both of them out there, particualrly as it does seem that the Compucorp is a fork.  As I commented to Peter, we have used 'stock' CiviCase for a while and I wanted to see whether there was anything interesting that had been developed to improve the experieince, even if it was just visual.

Answer (score 2):

To add some points to Andy's answer:

If what you want is new features being added, the CompuCorp one will do that faster.

Note that both of the extensions require the Shoreditch theme which, while reported to work on Wordpress and Drupal 8 with some tweaks, officially is only supported on Drupal 7.

There is also still core CiviCase. Both of the other extensions still rely on it underneath, but provide a different interface.